# How to provide custom code for InitializeComponent?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, designer, initializecomponent

When you modify column headers of a ListView at design time, the designer generates code to serialize column headers at run-time:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
    this.columnHeader1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
    this.columnHeader2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader();
    this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnHeader1,
        this.columnHeader2
    });
}
```

How does the forms-designer know that it should call the constructor for each column followed by a call to the AddRange method of the Columns property of the ListView? I need this for a ListView like UserControl I am writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I wanted to achieve was to customize the `InitializeComponent` code produced by my custom component. I found this MSDN article which describes how to do that:

[Customizing Code Generation in the .NET Framework Visual Designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx)

It appears that I need to write a [`CodeDomSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer.aspx) for my component, and generate a collection of [`CodeExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeexpression.aspx)'s describing my custom initialization code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use special attributes to tell the Visual Studio designer how to serialize properties in code.  See the MSDN reference for [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) for an example.  [This series of articles](http://amrelsehemy.net/post/2008/01/06/Custom-Controls-Design-Time-Support-Part-1-Design-Time-Attributes.aspx) also gives a good overview of the various attributes available to extend design time support for custom controls.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, what I need is more than what automatic serialization can provide. I found a MSDN article today described in my post below.